# async.waterfall not acting synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, waterfall

I'm trying to write a header of an MD5 hash token using crypto then return it back as a response. For some reason, it isn't actually running synchronously. I know JS is an asynchronous language, and that's really the only part I'm struggling with right now. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const async = require('async')

app.post('/pushurl/auth', (req, res) =>
    var data = req.body.form1data1 + '§' + req.body.form1data2 
        

    async.waterfall([
            function(callback) {
                var token = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest("hex");
                callback(null, token);
            },
            function(token, callback) {
                res.writeHead(301,
                    {Location: '/dashboard?token=' + token}
                );
                callback(null)
            },
            function(callback) {
                res.end();
                callback(null)
            }
        ]);
        
    }
});
```

Output:

```
Uncaught Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
<node_internals>/internal/errors.js:256
    No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
Process exited with code 1
```

Comment: `async.waterfall()` is just complicating matters here.  Not needed here at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is an asynchronous language, yes, but it can also do synchronous tasks very well. In your case, you don't need to do any async expect if you're dealing with promises.

If you write your code like in the example below it will just execute from top to bottom.

But the error (probably) occurred because you forgot to add an opening curly brace to your `app.post` callback, which results in the `data` var being immediately returned because of an implied return statement `() =>`  (implied), `() => {}` (explicit).

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const formidable = require('formidable');

app.post('/pushurl/auth', (req, res) => {

  const data = req.body.form1data1 + '§' + req.body.form1data2;
  const token = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest("hex");
  res.writeHead(301, {
    Location: '/dashboard?token=' + token
  });
  res.end();
        
});
```

Comment: Even removing all of the async.waterfall stuff, I still get the exact same output.

Comment: Then it might be a different part of your code that causes the error. Look for another endpoint where you return a response multiple times in a single endpoint.

Comment: even res.redirect seems to cause the same thing. I'll look around more to see what the problem still is.

Comment: The error is caused because somewhere you send back a response and *then* try to modify the headers. So look for that.

Comment: It turns out that another part of my js that was coming after that was getting executed to write another redirect after it was sent. Thanks for the help anyway. You saved me a big headache!